# ImageViews in a GridLayout

Tags: android, imageview, alignment

developers out there,

I want to make a GridLayout, which contains several imageViews, but the size of each cell of the GridLayout isn't set yet, because the GridLayoutchanges its size depending on the screen size (ConstraintLayout).

Now I've got the problem that when the Image is bigger than the cell, it is shown on the device (in the android studio it is shown).

I already tried things like setting the image as background, background-tint or change `android:background="@drawable/inventarslot"` to `app:background="@drawable/inventarslot"` which was said in other posts in this forum.

**This is my GridLayout:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gl_equipeditems"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8">
```

**This is my ImageView:**

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_slot1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Profil"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
```

Thank you for your help

Greetings Pumpanickel

Comment: How are you setting the images within the `GridLayout`.

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're displaying the images based on the screen size, I'm assuming you're also calculating the image size as well.

First, try to set your `ImageView` scale type to `fitCenter`, or any scale type that fits your needs. Example of scale types are shown below, [taken from here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide):

[image: Scale Types]

Later, programmatically change your `ImageView` width and height based on the calculations you made.

This way you'll be able to display all the images.

Comment: The image views are shown in android studio but when i start the app, they aren't shown in the device.

Comment: How are you loading the images?

Comment: I setted them in xml file... But I now deleted the gridlayout and set all the imageviews by coding in onCreate(), which works fine but surelly isn't the best way

Comment: AFAIK the xml part works as a preview. You do have to load them in code later on. You could even make use of an image lib such as Glide to handle the loading for you.